# Is it possible to call make network call for fragment from an activity

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am following MVP approach, and I have an activity containing 4 fragments. On App launch activity makes network call, and passes data to fragments.

In one of fragment i have `recycler view`, and it has `Swipe to Refresh`.

When user swipe to refresh i need to make network call from fragment, which i learnt is not a good idea, and also i am following `MVP` approach, so activity has the list of methods to execute in presenter, and presenter decided whether to grab data from local repository or remote.

So what should i do to perform `swipe to refresh` operation from a fragment.

Should i call activity method, and perform network call from there, and re pass the updated data to fragment, or is it fine to make a network call from fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is neither the Activity nor the fragment. The fragments and activities shall never "fetch" or "handle" data. Only display data. And deal with activity lifecycle with regards to this.

If you want to know further [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/23o0ic/best_practice_where_to_handle_data_fragment_or/) will be a good read for you.